# Unpacking nested dictionary list within python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I would be very grateful if someone could suggest a more Pythonic way of handling the following issue:

**Problem:**
I have a json object parsed into a python object (dict).  The issue I have is that the json object structure is a list of dictionaries(dict1).  These dictionaries contain a dictionary(dict2).

I would like to parse all the content of dict1 and combine the contents of dict2 within dict1.

Thereafter, I would like to parse this into pandas.

```js
json_object = {
  "data": [{
      "complete": "true",
      "data_two": {
        "a": "5",
        "b": "6",
        "c": "6",
        "d": "8"
      },
      "time": "2016-10-17",
      "End_number": 2
    },
    {
      "complete": "true",
      "data_two": {
        "a": "11",
        "b": "21",
        "c": "31",
        "d": "41"
      },
      "time": "2016-10-17",
      "End_number": 1
    }
  ],
  "Location": "DE",
  "End Zone": 5
}
```

My attempt:

```
    dataList =  json_object['data']  
    Unpacked_Data =   [(d['time'],d['End_number'], d['data_two'].keys(),d['data_two'].values()) for d in dataList]
```

Unpacked_Data is a list of tuples that now contains (time, end_number, [List of keys], [list of values])

To use this in a Pandas dataframe I would then need to unpack the two lists within my tuple. --> *is there an easy way to unpack lists within  a tuple?*

*Is there a better and more elegant/Pythonic way of approaching this problem?*

Thanks,
12avi

Comment: look if "zip" can help you

Answer (score 0):

One way (using `pandas`) is to start by putting everything into a dataframe, then apply `pd.Series` to it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(Unpacked_Data)
unpacked0 = df[2].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x)))
unpacked1 = df[3].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x)))
pd.concat((df[[0,1]],unpacked0,unpacked1))
```

The other way is to use list comprehension and argument unpacking:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[a,b,*c,*d] for a,b,c,d in Unpacked_Data])
```

However, the second method may not line up the way you want it if the packed lists are not of the same length.